# Adding a button that launches a new List Activity to a Fragment

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a fragment, which I added a button too in XML. I would like this button to launch a new menu of sorts so I have made it a list activity java class for it to point to when it's clicked, my issue is, where do I add the button and onclick method? In the page fragment class? When I try to do this it cannot resolve method "findviewbyid" which I am using to define the button of course. It also throws the same error for setContentView. I have as well tried putting this code in the Activity class for the frag but the app fails to load when I do this.  Here is the code I am trying to add to get the button to work:

```
    Button chOptions =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOptions);
    chOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.channel_menu);
        }
    });
```

The channel_menu is the List Activity I have created. Here is my Manifest declaration:

```
      <activity android:name=".ChannelMenu"
              android:label="Channel Options"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHANNELMENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject some widgets into the supporting view of `Fragment` then you should have a global reference to your created view in `onCreateView`:

```
View root;

       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flash_cards_box, container, false);

            context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    }
```

then inject the widgets somewhere else:

```
root.findViewById(...);
```

And for accessing `setContentView`, it's accessible via `Activity` class:

```
getActivity().setContentView(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown below add code into onActivityCreated() and use getView() method

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
// get the button view
Button chOptions =  (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.bOptions);
// set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
chOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.channel_menu);
    // Start new list activity
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                CarouselActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, my Fragment class has an oncreate view and I have decided to just use a context menu, Seems I cant add this to the oncreate view method. Any ideas, The method inflates the xml layout and that is all. Ive tried to just allow it to inflate an context menu but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Totally figured out I was working in the wrong activity, sorry man I should be good from here. Thanks.